# State Server Session Mode

Tags: session, session-state

Our project is designed to be hosted in two servers. One server will have the App Tier which contains the various database and file system access logic, and the other server will host the Web tier which will mainly contain the presentation logic.

The presentation layer in the Web Tier will connect to the App Tier through a Web Service.

I would like to know how can I access the session information which is stored in the other server. For example If Iam using State Server mode how can I access session information in App Tier(In Server 1), in the Web Tier(In Server 2).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't do this easily. It would better if you used a different session provider, for example SQL Server or implemented your session data using a [distributed caching mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CookieContainer` class in your AppTier. The web tier will pass cookies to web tier for each request.